# Variable in WHERE condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

The following SQL Query in a PHP code is not working, can someone helps me ?

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE destinataire = ':destinataire' ORDER BY maturity ASC");
$reponse->execute(array(
                ':destinataire'=>$_SESSION['login']
                ));
```

The correct query was the following :

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE destinataire = :destinataire ORDER BY maturity ASC");
```

Comment: What is the error message, or what about the code doesn't work?

Comment: @rrehbein After doing what JW suggest me, I got the following error
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\progecoo2\tasks.php on line 64

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when you want to parameterized the query, the parameters should not be wrapped with single quotes as they are **converted to string literals** (*meaning they are just regular values and not parameters anymore*). Remove the single quotes and it will work.

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE destinataire = :destinataire ORDER BY maturity ASC");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I get the following error : 
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\progecoo2\tasks.php on line 64

Comment: you have to use prepare, not query.

Comment: @Akam I did it into JW answer